# update variables using map function on spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing

Here is my code:

```
val dataRDD = sc.textFile(args(0)).map(line => line.split(" ")).map(x => Array(x(0).toInt, x(1).toInt, x(2).toInt))
var arr = new Array[Int](3)
printArr(arr)
dataRDD.map(x => {arr=x})
printArr(arr)
```

This code is not working properly. How can i make it work successfully?

Comment: Please explain how it should work, and how it's not working. Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: RDDs are immutable! You need to create a new one with the applied transformation.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so operations on RDDs are performed in parallel by different workers (usually on different machines in the cluster) and therefore you cannot pass in this type of "global" object `arr` to be updated. You see, each worker will receive their own copy of `arr` which they will update, but the driver will never know.

I'm guessing that what you want to do here is to collect all the arrays from the RDD, which you can do with a simple `collect` action:

```
val dataRDD = sc.textFile(args(0)).map(line => line.split(" ")).map(x => Array(x(0).toInt, x(1).toInt, x(2).toInt))
val arr = dataRDD.collect()
```

Where `arr` has type `Array[Array[Int]]`. You can then run through `arr` with normal array operations.

Comment: Thank you very much.and then,first ,i initialize the array arr(by definition),and then, i calculate the new array arr( dataRDD ),so ,i want to assign the new arr (dataRDD  )to old arr.it is an problem about update variables on spark  .can you help me?@Glennie Helles Sindholt

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to initialize `arr`, but if you for some reason need that you can add a `var arr = Array(new Array[Int](3))` and then change the line above to `arr = dataRDD.collect()`. Note that it is only the operations on RDDs that happen in parallel. Any operations you may do on `arr` (which is just a normal array) is processed on the driver (and not in parallel)