# Variable not updated

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is perhaps very basic but I am certainly missing something here.
It is all within a method, where I increment/alter a variable within a child/sub scope (it could be within a `if` block, or like here, within a `map`)

However, the result is unchanged variable. e.g. here, sum remains zero after the `map`. whereas, it should come up to 3L.

What am I missing ?

```
val resultsMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Long]
resultsMap("0001") = 0L
resultsMap("0003") = 2L
resultsMap("0007") = 1L
var sum = 0L
resultsMap.mapValues(x => {sum = sum + x})
//  I first wrote this, but then got worried and wrote more explicit version too, same behaviour
// resultMap.mapValues(sum+=_)
println("total of counts for txn ="+sum) // sum still 0
```

-- Update 
I have similar behaviour where a loop is not updating the variable outside the loop. looking for text on variable scoping, but not found the golden source yet. all help is appreciated.

```
var cnt : Int = 0
    rdd.foreach(article => {
      if (<something>) {
        println(<something>) // being printed
        cnt += 1
        println("counter is now "+cnt) // printed correctly
      }
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update variables using map function on spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774527/update-variables-using-map-function-on-spark)

Comment: You have two different problems. The first (`mapValues` producng a view) has been answered. Your edited one is because Spark runs the loop across many workers, each of which gets their own copy of `cnt` and the originating one is NOT updated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774527/update-variables-using-map-function-on-spark?rq=1 (and a bunch of other questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should proceed like this:

```
val sum = resultsMap.values.reduce(_+_)
```

You just get your `values` and then add them up with `reduce`.

**EDIT**:

The reason `sum` stays unchanged is that `mapValues` produces a *view*, which means (among other things) the new map won't be computed unless the resulting view is acted upon, so in this case - the code block updating sum is simply *never executed*.

To see this - you can "force" the view to "materialize" (compute the new map) and see that sum is updated, as expected:

```
var sum = 0L
resultsMap.mapValues(x => {sum = sum + x}).view.force
println("SUM: " + sum) // prints 3
```

See related discussion here: [Scala: Why mapValues produces a view and is there any stable alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882642/scala-why-mapvalues-produces-a-view-and-is-there-any-stable-alternatives)

Comment: Appreciate your pointer about mapValues giving only a view and therefore the effect. However, i have  similar behaviour and i believe its linked to variable scoping.
-- Updated the question